# jQuery dynamic selector returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure that I have overlooked something, but this is confounding to me.

starting html:

```
<div id="col-header-1"> ... </div>
```

Using Instafeed (js plugin) to get instagram images - working fine. outputs the following correctly (within col-header-1):

```
<div class="instagram-headers" data-highres="http://origincache-frc.fbcdn.net/10175356_1376290249321406_570358524_s.jpg"></div>
```

this does not work, url returns undefined:

```
function replaceCssBackgroundWithImage(target){
  var url = $('#' + target + ' > .instagram-headers').attr('data-highres');
  $('#' + target).css('background-image','url(' + url + ')');
}
```

result

```
<div style="background-image: url('undefined');" id="col-header-1">
```

so it gets target correctly.

Stepping through in (firefox's) console yields the correct result:

```
target = 'col-header-1' //=>"col-header-1"

var url = $('#' + target + ' > .instagram-headers').attr('data-highres'); //=> undefined

url //=> "http://origincache-frc.fbcdn.net/10175356_1376290249321406_570358524_s.jpg"

$('#' + target).css('background-image','url(' + url + ')'); //=> [object Object]
```

result

```
<div style="background-image: url("http://origincache-frc.fbcdn.net/10175356_1376290249321406_570358524_s.jpg");" id="col-header-1">
```

im at a loss, any help is appreciated,

thanks!

UPDATE: Instafeed Constructor

```
function getMultipleFeeds(targets){
var feeds = [];
var opts = {};
for (var i=0,len=targets.length;i<len;i++){
if (targets[i].match('header')){
    opts = {
        tagName: "TAG",
        target: targets[i],
        limit: '1',
        get: 'tagged',
        user:'USER',
        clientId:'CLIENTID',
        template:'<div class="instagram-headers" data-highres="{{image}}"></div>',
        useHttp:true,
        before: replaceCssBackgroundWithImage(targets[i]),
    };
...
feeds.push(new Instafeed(opts));
  }
return feeds;
}

var myFeeds = getMultipleFeeds(['col-header-1','col-header-2','col-header-3','instafeed','banner']);

for(var i=0, len=myFeeds.length; i < len; i++) {
  myFeeds[i].run();
}
```

Comment: Where is `replaceCssBackgroundWithImage` being called in your code?

Comment: in the Instafeed constructor, with the before parameter - before: replaceCssBackgroundWithImage(targets[i]),
 https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js#advanced-options

Comment: can you add the code for your instafeed constructor

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the instafeed documentation, you probably want to call `replaceCssBackgroundWithImagemethod` in the `after` callback, rather than the `before` callback. Try changing before to after :

```
function getMultipleFeeds(targets){
var feeds = [];
var opts = {};
for (var i=0,len=targets.length;i<len;i++){
if (targets[i].match('header')){
opts = {
    tagName: "TAG",
    target: targets[i],
    limit: '1',
    get: 'tagged',
    user:'USER',
    clientId:'CLIENTID',
    template:'<div class="instagram-headers" data-highres="{{image}}"></div>',
    useHttp:true,
    after: replaceCssBackgroundWithImage(targets[i]),
};
...
feeds.push(new Instafeed(opts));
  }
return feeds;
}

var myFeeds = getMultipleFeeds(['col-header-1','col-header-2','col-header-3','instafeed','banner']);

for(var i=0, len=myFeeds.length; i < len; i++) {
  myFeeds[i].run();
}
```

The reason being that the element you are trying to target hasn't been added to the DOM at the point you are trying to access it, thus returning undefined.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't change the result.

Comment: i have updated the code slightly for the after callback, try that!

Comment: after asking jshint to not complain about defining fn's in loops, this actually breaks further, not inserting the style="..." at all.

Comment: ok, change it back to the above (use after) - in your replaceCssBackgroundWithImage function, can you add the following on the 1st line : console.log(target,$('#' + target + ' > .instagram-headers')); and let me know what you get out in the console.

Comment: "col-header-1" [object Object]
"col-header-2" [object Object]
"col-header-3" [object Object]

Comment: try instead of `var url = $('#' + target + ' > .instagram-headers').attr('data-highres');` to use : `var url = $('#' + target + ' > .instagram-headers').data('highres');`

Comment: Same result. Im beginning to think that its an issue with the callback functions in Instafeed, not waiting until after/success as they should.
on the else case ive added before,after & success console.log() fn's similar to what you've suggested above - they all return undefined on load, but get the right value when manually entered into the console.


maybe because im pushing several new objects at once.

Comment: Yeah it would seem to me that the callback function is being called before those elements are being added to the DOM, so may well be an issue with Instafeed. Perhaps adding a timeout of say 500ms before calling the function would help?